# Класс окружность

Tags: c++, классы

Добрый вечер возник вопрос с классом. Нужно написать класс окружность в котором поля класса - радиус, координаты центра.
Методы:
Изменение радиуса, изменение координат центра, вычисление периметра, вычисление площади, вывод информации о окружности.
Вот мой код:

```
using namespace std;

class Circle 
{
private:
    int r;
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    int Point(int x_, int y_, int r_) 
    {
        return x = x_, y = y_, r = r_;
    }
    double Perimeter() 
    {
        return 2 * 3.1415 * r;
    }
    double Square() 
    {
        return 3.1415 * r * r;
    }
    void print() 
    {
        cout<< "x = " << x << " || " <<"y = " << y << " || " <<"r = " << r << " || " << "Периметр = " << Perimeter << "||" << "Площадь = " << Square << endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    int Perimeter = 0;
    int Square = 0;
    setlocale(0, "");
    Circle c;
    c.Point(2, 4, 6);
    Perimeter = c.Perimeter();
    Square = c.Square();
    c.print();
}
```

В методе print компилятор говорит:

> C3867 "Circle::Perimeter": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член  Circle
> C3867 "Circle::Square": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член Circle

Не могу понять проблему с указателем.
И второй вопрос насчет изменения радиуса и координат. Как это можно реализовать. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: а какая проблема с изменением координат и радиуса то? Просто создаете методы, которые устанавливают новые значение - и все...

Comment: Метод `Point` выглядит как неудавшаяся попытка написать конструктор. Конструкторы имеют имя класса.

Comment: Ошибки вызваны попыткой печати имени метода `<< Perimeter <<`. Добавьте круглые скобки: `<< Perimeter() <<`.

Comment: Перемешаны типы `int` и `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в функции `print`

Вы забыли вызвать методы:

```
"Периметр = " << Perimeter() << "||" << "Площадь = " << Square() << endl;
```

---

Также у вас есть проблемы с преобразованиями double в int.

Answer (score 0):

Perimeter и Square являются членами класса. Если вы хотите получать их адреса,  то нужно  так: &Circle::Perimeter и &Circle::Square, но наверняка вы хотели их вызвать и забыли добавить скобки : `Perimeter()` и `Square()`.

А также вы не выполнили задание до конца, так как отсутствуют

> Методы: Изменение радиуса, изменение координат центра